# How do I serve video files via progressive download in NGINX?

Tags: nginx, server, video-streaming, streaming, nginx-config

I'm trying to get a basic video streaming server in NGINX on a Raspberry Pi, but I can't seem to figure out any way to serve video files without downloading the entire file to first, then playing.

It should accept any mp4 files in any subdirectories without any extra path stuff (so `/var/www/media/some_directory/something.mp4` would translate to `http://mediaserv.local/some_directory/something.mp4`.

I have tried many different configuration files, my current one is as follows;

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        alias /var/www/media;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.mp4$ {
        mp4;
        mp4_buffer_size 4M;
        mp4_max_buffer_size 12M;
        add_header Cache-Control 'public, max-age=604800, immutable';
    }
}
```

But when I attempt to get a file in `/var/www/media/Testing/TestVideo.mp4` via `http://mediaserv.local/Testing/TestVideo.mp4`, it returns 404 not found. I haven't got that much NGINX experience so I have no clue how to go from here.